# Obj-C Pattern & Object Memory footprints

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsview, nsobject

In this particular cocoa project I have properties for a set of views and there respective subviews being parsed from an xml file.

Only one view in the set is active at a time and the views may change frequently.

Would it be best to

A.) Initialize the view objects with the parsed properties and store a reference to them in an Array to be used when necessary.

b.) Initialize an NSObject with the parsed properties which can in turn create it's respective view upon demand via a factory.

The logic behind this is that the NSViews not being used (majority) could be deallocated by ARC when needed as they would not have a persistent reference.

This begs another question.

Is all of this done in the background anyways (Since NSView is an NSObject subclass) when an NSView is referenced but not being displayed?

Comment: How is this ARC related?

Comment: Edited title for clarity due to the questions relation to ARC being marginal.

Comment: It's generally better, when dealing with a large volume of data, to handle the data in "condensed" form and only construct the various View components when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing implementing your own version of xibs. I'm going to say, the "best" answer is reconsider your design decision. There is probably a better and easier way to achieve your desired result.

The memory difference between an array of NSObjects describing all the properties and subviews of a NSView versus an array of NSViews is nominal.

The most memory efficient way is to lazily deserialize the single view through a NSWindowController or NSViewController.